# Step into method directly while stepping over getters

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is it possible while debugging in eclipse, to *step directly into* a method i.e. the below `lotsOfArgs` bypassing the need to step in/out (F5 then F7) all of the parameters that are passed to the method ?

```
private void method() {
    lotsOfArgs(getA(), getB(), getC(), getD(), getE(), getF());
}
```

I also want to avoid putting a breakpoint inside `lotsOfArgs` since this is only one of many methods I may or may not want to *step directly into*.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> = Step into selection

[facepalm] Although I searched in all the menus before asking this question, I happened to see the option when I did a `right click > Step into selection (Ctrl+F5)`. Then I also noticed it was in the Run menu all along: `Run > Step into selection (Ctrl+F5)`.